# Can I use Angular web components in an Angular lib?

Tags: angular, angular6, web-component, angular7, angular-library

I want to create an Angular library which I need to use in my backbone project.

I have already tried the thing with Angular web components and it worked.
I used the @angular/elements.
Now I need the same thing to work with an Angular Library.

Comment: yes you can use angular web components in angular library

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan could u help me with that??